# The event listener added by window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)") is not triggered in Safari on iOS 17 when the app is installed as a PWA

Tags: safari, progressive-web-apps

Is it just me, or is there a bug in Safari on iOS 17 where the event listener added by window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)") is not triggered? There was no such issue in Safari on iOS 16. The issue occurs only when the web app is installed on the home screen as a PWA. In the browser, everything is working fine.

The code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleColorSchemeChange(event) {
      // this listener won't trigger when the web app is installed as PWA on the iPhone's home screen
      const newColorScheme = event.matches ? "dark" : "light";
      setCurrentDarkMode(newColorScheme);
    }

    window
      .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
      .addEventListener("change", handleColorSchemeChange);

    return () => {
      window
        .matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)")
        .removeEventListener("change", handleColorSchemeChange);
    };
  }, []);
```

I tried installing the PWA application (for example, timezones.digital) on an iPhone and toggled the system's dark/light mode

Comment: This is definitely a bug in iOS 17. I've tried various ways to force the correct theme, but it appears that the value of prefers-color-scheme never changes from the one that the app launched with. Here's some discussion on Apple Dev forums https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/739154?login=true&page=1#774253022